# VeriticleAlignment Center doesn't work in Windows Phone 8 within a Grid

Tags: windows-phone-8

VeriticleAlignment Center doesn't work in Windows Phone 8 within a Grid. Can anyone help me how to do it?

Comment: If the answer I provided worked for you, please could you mark it as the answer by accepting the solution. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set it on the child within the grid itself e.g.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Canvas Height="300" Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        ...
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Note: Canvas is just used as an example here, could be any control.